# Open same fragment after activity recreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, recreate

I have fragment container activity in which I replace fragments as per operations. In one fragment I am providing options to change primary color for app. So user can change toolbar and other components tint color. 
but after applying theme i recreate activity so my toolbar in base activity also reinitialized with new color code.

Now my problem is my app sequence is like this 
**Setting > User settings > Theme Settings**

so when user change theme i want to display same fragment again after recreate. 
I have seen other questions also and applied logic also but not working for me.

**Code to change theme**

```
private void setThemePreference(String primary, String primaryDark, String text) {
    int requiredLength = 0;

    if (primary.length() < 6) {
        requiredLength = 6 - primary.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredLength; i++) {

            primary = "0" + primary;
        }
    }

    if (primaryDark.length() < 6) {
        requiredLength = 6 - primaryDark.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredLength; i++) {

            primaryDark = "0" + primaryDark;
        }
    }

    if (text.length() < 6) {
        requiredLength = 6 - text.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < requiredLength; i++) {

            text = "0" + text;
        }
    }

    UserPreferenceManager.preferencePutString(
        AppConstants.SharedPreferenceKeys.PrimaryColor,primary);
    UserPreferenceManager.preferencePutString(
        AppConstants.SharedPreferenceKeys.PrimaryDarkColor, primaryDark);
    UserPreferenceManager.preferencePutString(
        AppConstants.SharedPreferenceKeys.PrimaryTextColor, text);
    UserPreferenceManager.preferencePutBoolean(
        AppConstants.SharedPreferenceKeys.IS_ThemeChanged, true);

    TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity())
        .addNextIntent(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class))
        .addNextIntent(getActivity().getIntent())
        .startActivities();

    // applied this also
    //getActivity().recreate();

    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Code to open theme fragment

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
    .addToBackStack(TAG)
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    .commit();
```

Please guys help. I have not much experience and not even fresh new developer.

Comment: can you please show how you are handling fragments in your code

Comment: Are you calling parent activity again after changing the theme ?

Comment: @PratikVyas you means how i open fragment ?

Comment: @Himanshuarora Yes to change theme in all previous activity i recreate task builder.

Comment: yep ,share that code too so that one can see what you are exactly doing and can help you out

Comment: @PratikVyas check my updated question.

Comment: @dev_krupa So if you are calling parent activity again then just send the intent value(any boolean value) while starting the parent activity and in your parent activity 's onCreate just check that if intent value is present then just load the same fragment again .

Comment: you can call setting fragment/Usersettings fragment  and clearbackstackstack using code.

Comment: @Vasant can you explain how ?

Comment: see @pratik vyas's answer.he define one method gotosamefragent().that way you can call fragment and clear all backstack fragment.

Comment: @Vasant no but i want backstack same it is. I can't tell user oops your previous page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help as you have stored is_theme changed,

**now use Intent to restart the activity**

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
```

When activity starts in its onResume method check whether theme is changed or not, and if it was changed then call the fragment

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(UserPreferenceManager.preferencePutBoolean(
                AppConstants.SharedPreferenceKeys.IS_ThemeChanged, true)){
            UserPreferenceManager.preferencePutBoolean(
                AppConstants.SharedPreferenceKeys.IS_ThemeChanged, false)
            YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
            activity.goToSecondFragment();
        }
    }
```

The method

```
public void goToSameFragment(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment sameFragment = new sameFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, sameFragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: If i do this what about backstack of fragment.

Comment: do you want to maintain the backstack or not  ?

Comment: ft.addToBackStack(null); is  used to handle backstack if you want to do it

Comment: @PratikVyas IT will not work. read question she want to change toolbar color also and todo so she has to recreate activity. but your code only open same fragment no previous fragments.

Comment: @PratikVyas I don't know where to put this code. and as androidnoobdev mentioned what about user and setting fragments.

Comment: I have changed the code so that it will open the activity and can open the fragment check it now

Comment: @PratikVyas last changes not working. when user press recent app button and opens again same app it will call on resume and at that time it directly start that fragment.

Comment: for that reason only I have put that condition whether your theme is updated and you have to maintain that boolean preference.

Comment: check it, now I have maintained the preference in onResume

Comment: @PratikVyas no that flag can't be false. on the basis of that I apply theme when user restart app. so when user have closed app for 2-3 days next time it will open I apply theme using this flag only. upvote question if you think its good question.

Comment: @dev_krupa then create another flag to maintain our logic in the same manner and use it.